# how do i get this.name thought JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<img id="image1" name="image_Group1" src="1-1.png" onclick="update(this.src,this.name);">

function update(_src, name){
document.cookie = name;
alert(document.cookie);
}
```

i get "undefined" on this.name , how do i get this.name pass to my JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a different problem. Your code works, take a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/pfwz9kw9/):

```html
<img id="image1" name="image_Group1" src="1-1.png" onclick="update(this.src,this.name);">
```

```js
function update(_src, name){
    document.cookie = name;
    alert(document.cookie);
}
```

Try separating your issue and test it that way. This helps a lot of times.

Comment: The fiddle is working for you? What browser are you using?

Comment: chrome , the fiddle work but i checked everything is the same code i used.

Comment: i still get undefined

Comment: Debug it, try `onclick="console.log(this)"` and see what happens in chrome's console

Comment: try: `onclick="alert(this);"` what is in the message? It is [Object HtmlImageElement]?
Then `onclick="alert(this.name);"` ...

Comment: ohh the alert(this.name); get the name.

Comment: thank i got it ~ some of my other code seem to bugged it , i put the code on top of it and everything go the way.

Answer (score 0):

I know why your code is not working. You've done Everything good so far. But I think you are running your code directly not on a web server, e.g. like `'file:///C:/file.html'` or something instead of `'http://localhost/file.html'`. Go ahead and run your script on a webserver I'm sure it'll run.

This happens because chrome does not store the cookies unless it is associated with some domain.

Good Luck!